# Choose in combobox and show datagridwiev

Tags: c#, sql, database, datagridview, combobox

I want to pull the tables from the database and add, delete, update on these tables.I choose the table name in combobox and I want to show on datagridwiev.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string table_name= comboBox1.Text;
        this.table_name.TableAdapter.Fill(this.MyDataBase1DataSet.table_name);
    }
```

but this not working.How can i do that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use if in C#,

example

```
string selected = this.ComboBox.GetItemText (this.ComboBox.SelectedItem);

// table_name manually
if (selected) {
this.table_name.TableAdapter.Fill (this.MyDataBase1DataSet.table_name);
}
```

You cannot add a variable to MyDataBase1DataSet. "table_name" because it will be considered a function of MyDataBase1DataSet, not a variable